# install google earth on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, deb, google-earth

I've tried several times to install Google Earth for Ubuntu 12.10 and keep getting installation errors - usually dependency errors. I've followed the instructions to a T, and still have yet to get a clean install.

I've used the usual `wget` command to download the `.deb` file or used Google's own download file utility, then did a `sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb`, etc., etc.

Also tried for for 32 bit system, still nothing works.

Does anyone know how to:

1. Download a proper and correct `.deb` file?
2. To install Google Earth from that `.deb` file? This has become exasperating.

Comment: What are the dependency errors you're actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following sequences in terminal for this matter :

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main"/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list'

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable
```

hope that works ;)

Answer (score 0):

To install a .deb file.

Use

```
  $ sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

There could be broken installation so use

```
  $ sudo apt-get install -f
```

`-f/--fix-broken` --> equivalent